# Check if two Strings share a common substring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any fast way in JavaScript to find out if 2 Strings contain the same substring? e.g. I have these 2 Strings: "audi is a car" and "audiA8".

As you see the word "audi" is in both strings but we cannot find it out with a simple `indexOf` or RegExp, because of other characters in both strings.

Comment: `if (string1 === string2) { /*identical*/ }` - What are you _really_ trying to ask, how to test whether a particular substring is in two different strings, or whether there exists some substring that appears in two different strings, or...? Could you please show an example _input_ and the desired _output_?

Comment: why do you need indexOf or RegExp? just compare the 2 with '==='.

Comment: If the two strings are `abc` and `cde`, should they be considered "identical" because of `c`?

Comment: if you know what the substring is, you can perform indexOf on both the strings to check if the substring exists.

Comment: @nicmon, I've edited the question to remove a mention of "identical", as that's misleading. If I changed the meaning too much, please edit it to clarify.

Comment: I removed the duplicate because that question has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the similar text function implementation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301070226/http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text/). It returns the number of matching chars in both strings.

For your example it would be:

```
similar_text("audi is a car", "audiA8") // -> 4
```

which means that strings have 4-char common substring.

Answer (score 10):

The standard tool for doing this sort of thing in Bioinformatics is the [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) program. It is used to compare two fragments of molecules (like DNA or proteins) to find where they align with each other - basically where the two strings (sometimes multi GB in size) share common substrings.

The basic algorithm is simple, just systematically break up one of the strings into pieces and compare the pieces with the other string. A simple implementation would be something like:

```
// Note: not fully tested, there may be bugs:

function subCompare (needle, haystack, min_substring_length) {

    // Min substring length is optional, if not given or is 0 default to 1:
    min_substring_length = min_substring_length || 1;

    // Search possible substrings from largest to smallest:
    for (var i=needle.length; i>=min_substring_length; i--) {
        for (j=0; j <= (needle.length - i); j++) {
            var substring = needle.substr(j,i);
            var k = haystack.indexOf(substring);
            if (k != -1) {
                return {
                    found : 1,
                    substring : substring,
                    needleIndex : j,
                    haystackIndex : k
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        found : 0
    }
}
```

You can modify this algorithm to do more fancy searches like ignoring case, fuzzy matching the substring, look for multiple substrings etc. This is just the basic idea.

Comment: Very nice function. If you don't mind, I'll [steal](https://github.com/psychowood/ng-torrent-ui/commit/9046410c51859c2964b0d305d3903c1954ec88ef) it. :)

Comment: Is this a correct implementation of the [BLAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST_(biotechnology)) algorithm? BLAST normally uses a heuristic search, but this appears to be a simple [brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).

Comment: @AndersonGreen No. I said this is a very simplistic implementation of the core idea behind BLAST. If you need BLAST then you should use BLAST (eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/blastjs or https://www.npmjs.com/package/blastutils)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about any simpler method, but this should work:

```
if(a.indexOf(substring) != -1 && b.indexOf(substring) != -1) { ... }
```

where `a` and `b` are your strings.

Comment: But if you still do not know the substring, how could you know before?

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = "audi is a car";
var b = "audiA8";

var chunks = a.split(" ");
var commonsFound = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    if(b.indexOf(chunks[i]) != -1) commonsFound++;
}

alert(commonsFound + " common substrings found.");
```

Comment: the substrings may have spaces